# vertical text align inside LI error both in inline and external css

Tags: html, css

am trying to aling text in middle in vertical

- i used both inline and external css but i could find any positive result 
  i don't know whats wrong is going on and can't find the error

  ```
  <div id="leftmenu">
              <ul id="leftmenuidfrmslt" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                  <a href="#"><li><span class="flaticon-smart"></span>Item one</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Item two</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Item four</li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li>Item five</li></a>
              </ul>
          </div>
  ```

## CSS

```
span{color:green;font-size:30px;}
#leftmenu{margin-left:100px;}
#leftmenuidfrmslt
{
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
width: 300px;
}

#leftmenuidfrmslt li
{
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0.25em;
border-top: 1px dotted gray;
height:45px;
}
#leftmenuidfrmslt li:hover{background-color:#ffffcc;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
```

## output

[image]

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/L5dstx2z/)

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: see http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ for a little intro on how to use vertical-align. it may help.

Comment: @gaurav5430 check my output and can you make text in center

Comment: can you post how do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @gaurav5430 i want font icon and text to be vertically center check this i want in this type http://jsfiddle.net/345c5/

Comment: do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tso6yc8x/2/

Comment: @gaurav5430 yes but i have many font icon and i cant add class for each icon in css

Comment: @gaurav5430 fianally i found what i want here is what i want http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/L5dstx2z/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62770/discussion-between-sanoj-lawrence-and-gaurav5430).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add "vertical-align: middle" for icon(span) - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meuwka/mck257pm/)

```
#leftmenuidfrmslt li span{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but! your html wrong. correct structure:

```
<div id="leftmenu">
    <ul id="leftmenuidfrmslt">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Item one</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#leftmenu {
    margin-left:100px;
}
#leftmenuidfrmslt {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
    width: 300px;
}
#leftmenuidfrmslt li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px dotted gray;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
}
#leftmenuidfrmslt li span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:green;
    font-size:30px;
}
#leftmenuidfrmslt li:hover {
    background-color:#ffffcc;
}
```

And better to use classes instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code, you should never have anything other than an `li` element as a child of a list.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lat8ofg/)

EDIT: If you don't like the vertical spacing of the icon, just play with the `top` attribute in `#left ul li a span`. I was just checking it and I think I like 11px better.

CSS:

```
#left ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:300px;
    border-top:1px dotted gray;
}

#left ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px dotted gray;
    border-collapse:collapsed;
}

#left ul li a {
    display: block;
    height:45px;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height:45px;
}

#left ul li a span {
    position:relative;
    color:green;
    top: 8px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

#left ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#FFC;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a new fiddle, I left a line out of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your `li` elements going to have more than one line of text? If not, you can do this simply by setting the `line-height` of the `li` equal to the `height`.

```
#leftmenuidfrmslt li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.25em;
    border-top: 1px dotted gray;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tso6yc8x/)

Comment: am using font-icon so i get text little bellow please look at question thats how am getting

Comment: Just add `display:inline-block;` to the span. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tso6yc8x/1/)

Comment: still i don't get positive result please add font icon and check